# How can I restrict form input to specific characters with a regex?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a made a regex for user to only allow these characters to be input. If user writes for example '@' it should not allow it, but in my code if user press @ and than press the tab the '@' still remains there.

```js
function onlyAlphabet(inputVal) {
  var patt = /^[a-zA-Z.123456789]+$/;
  
  if (patt.test(inputVal)) {
    document.getElementById('facebook').value = inputVal;
  } else {
    var txt = inputVal.slice(0, -1);
    document.getElementById('facebook').value = txt;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="fw-bold my-1 fs-7" id="text-color1">Facebook</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook" onkeypress="onlyAlphabet(value)" id="facebook" class="form-control" name="facebook" value="<?php echo $row['facebook'] ?>" style="padding-left: 0 !important; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8; border-radius: 0 !important;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `onchange="onlyAlphabet(value)"` and `onblur="onlyAlphabet(value)"` to make sure it would be called in any circumstances

Answer (score 1):

you could do it using any of these 3 ways -

- 1. `onChange="onlyAlphabet(value)"`  - when the value of the input changes
- 2. `onKeyUp="onlyAlphabet(value)"`  - or onKeyDown, when a key is released/pressed
- 3. `onBlur="onlyAlphabet(value)"` - when the focus leaves the input...

Answer (score 0):

Must set  oninput instead of onkeypress